# OK to remove board in attic?

Tags: framing

Is the 1x6 board at a 45 degree angle in this picture in any way load bearing or required?

Assuming it was a temporary support when the house was built. Early 60s construction.

It's inconveniently in front of an LB / conduit transition and hvac I'd like easier access to.

[image]

Comment: Plywood is usually not used as support like this. Some lazy workers may left it.

Comment: It's the angled 1x6 that is really in the way.

Comment: Is it actually fastened to anything, or will it move when you push on it?  It looks like it has no function, but it also looks like somebody deliberately put it there....so I wonder if somebody kludged something together.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this picture - is the top nailed in place and the corner clipped off like it's supposed to be here, or was it just left lying there by someone careless and too lazy to pick it up and haul it back downstairs? It _could_ be diagonal bracing for the gable end, but a 1x is not likely to be used for that unless it was the only thing available...

Comment: Two nails into the joist on the right of the picture, three into the top left, and yes the corner is clipped off to fit.

Comment: I believe it was put there to keep the end rafter true. We used to do similar but normally used the board for decking. Now with the roof in place and what we can see it is not doing anything.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is the temporary support for erection. A diagonal "support" would require much more sturdy stuff (a 2x stud) and well-fastened end connections.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Appreciate the comments.